# getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I run the project on which I have a mongo compass and all settings are given, everything is normal, but when I try to run on another computer(mac) I getting this error, is it possible?

```js
async function start() {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
  });

  try {
    await MongoClient.connect(
      'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017',
      { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
      function (err, db) {
        var dbase = db.db('Server');
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('connected!');
          /*  dbase.createCollection('posts') */
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Server error', e.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  ngrok.connect(
    {
      proto: 'http',
      addr: process.env.PORT,
    },
    (err, url) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error while connecting Ngrok', err);
        return new Error('Ngrok Failed');
      }
    }
  );
}
start();
```

Comment: Can you please format your code? You can use markdown to add syntax highlighting.

Comment: Can you check please, is it right code below?

Answer (score 0):

```
 async function start() {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
  });

  try {
    await MongoClient.connect(
      'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017',
      { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
      function (err, db) {
        var dbase = db.db('Server');
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('connected!');
          /*  dbase.createCollection('posts') */
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Server error', e.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  ngrok.connect(
    {
      proto: 'http',
      addr: process.env.PORT,
    },
    (err, url) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error while connecting Ngrok', err);
        return new Error('Ngrok Failed');
      }
    }
  );
}
start();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).